# Which Google API allows me to retrieve google account user info and store in a database?

Tags: android, database, google-api

Which Google API allows me to retrieve google account user info and store in a database?

I have been looking at Oauth2.0 get access tokens to get authorisation for the People API v1 however I need to know if this is the correct way and whether this is the best API to use.

Comment: People api or you could use the userinfo endpoint but the People api is probably the most reliable.

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks Ill take a look and feedback